# Как задать правильный location, чтобы часть url не стиралась?

Tags: nginx

Есть server example.com. Он перенаправляет на 127.0.0.1:8080/ (это указано в proxy_pass), и возвращает мне страницу tomcat как положено. Но далее я не могу перемещаться по странице, к примеру на /manager/html, тк стирается часть "/tomcat". Как это исправить? Конфиг такой:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /tomcat {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

P.s в гайде, по которому делаю, указано, что в proxy pass нужно удалить слеш. Но тогда даже example.com/tomcat отдаёт ошибку 404.

При этом, если прописать перед /manager/html "/tomcat/" - то всё работает

Comment: nginx тут ни при чём, исправлять проблему надо в том месте, которое генерирует ссылки в html-коде — как-то объяснять ему, что в начале всех ссылок нужно приписать /tomcat

Comment: А где он генерирует?